# error "r" is not defined when I try to log it into the console

Tags: javascript

When trying to test my code using the variable r. Which I defined with window.r , It gives me an error variable not defined.

When I type `r.parseIngredients()` into the command line, the following error occurs:

> VM3439:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined
>       at :1:1

### index.js file:

```
import Search from './models/Search';
import Recipe from './models/Recipe';
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
import { elements, renderLoader, clearLoader } from './views/base';

// const search = new Search('pizza');
// console.log(search);
// search.getResults();

/**  GLobal state of the app
 *  - Search object
 *  - Current Recipe Object
 *  - Shopping list object
 *  - Liked recipes
 */
const state = {};

/*
-- Search Controller
*/
    const controlSearch = async () => {
    // 1) Get query from view
    // const query = searchView.getInput();
    const query = 'pizza';

    if (query) {
        // 2) New seach object and add to state
        state.search = new Search(query);

        // 3) Prepare UI for results
        searchView.clearInput();
        searchView.clearResults();
        renderLoader(elements.searchRes);

        try {    
            // 4) Search for recipes
            await state.search.getResults();

            // 5) Render results on UI
            clearLoader();
            searchView.renderResults(state.search.results);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Something wrong with the search...');
            clearLoader();
        }
    }
}

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});


// Testing
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});

elements.searchResPages.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const btn = e.target.closest('.btn-inline');
    if (btn) {
        const goToPage = parseInt(btn.dataset.goto, 10);
        searchView.clearResults();
        searchView.renderResults(state.search.results, goToPage);
    }
});

/*
Recipe Controller
*/
const controlRecipe = async () => {
    // Get ID from url
    const id = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    console.log(id);

    if (id) {
        // Prepare UI for changes

        // Create new recipe object
        state.recipe = new Recipe(id);

        // Testing 
        window.r = state.recipe;

        try {
            // get recipe data
            await state.recipe.getRecipe();

            // Calculate servings and time
            state.recipe.calcTime();
            state.recipe.calcServings();

            // Render recipe
            console.log(state.recipe);

        } catch (err) {
            alert('Error processing recipe!');
        }

    }
};

// window.addEventListener('hashchange', controlRecipe);
// window.addEventListener('load', controlRecipe);

['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, controlRecipe));
```

### Recipe.js file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { key, proxy } from '../config.js'

export default class Recipe {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    async getRecipe() {
        try {
            const res = await axios(`${proxy}http://food2fork.com/api/get?key=${key}&rId=${this.id}`);
            this.title = res.data.recipe.title;
            this.author = res.data.recipe.publisher;
            this.img = res.data.recipe.image_url;
            this.url = res.data.recipe.source_url;
            this.ingredients = res.data.recipe.ingredients;
            console.log(res);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Something went wrong')
        }
    }

    calcTime() {
        // Assuming that we need 15 min for each 3 ingredients
        const numIng =  this.ingredients. length;
        const periods = Math.ceil(numIng / 3);
        this.time = periods * 15;
    }

    calcServings() {
        this.servings = 4;
    }

    parseIngredients() {
        const unitsLong = ['tablespoons', 'tablespoon', 'ounces', 'ounce', 'teaspoons', 'teaspoon', 'cups', 'pounds'];
        const unitsShort = ['tbsp', 'tbsp', 'oz', 'oz', 'tsp', 'tsp', 'cup', 'pound'];

        const newIngredients = this.ingredients.map(el => {
            // 1) Uniform units
            let ingredient = el.toLowerCase();
            unitsLong.forEach((unit, i) => {
                ingredient = ingredient.replace(unit, unitsShort[i]);
            });

            // 2) Remove parentheses
            ingredient = ingredient.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ' ')

            // 3) Parse ingredients into count, unit and ingredient
            const arrIng = ingredient.split(' ');
            const unitIndex = arrIng.findIndex(el2 => unitsLong.includes(el2));

            let objIng;
            if (unitIndex > -1) {
                // There is a unit
                // Ex. 4 1/2 cups, arrCount is [4, 1/2]
                // 4 cups, arrCount is [4]
                const arrCount = arrIng.slice(0, unitIndex);

                let count;
                if (arrCount.length === 1) {
                    count = arrIng[0];
                } else {
                    count = eval(arrIng.slice(0, unitIndex).join('+'));
                }

            } else if (parseInt(arrIng[0], 10)) {
                // There is no unit, but the first element is a number
                objIng = {
                    count: parseInt(arrIng[0], 10),
                    unit: '',
                    ingredient: arrIng.slice(1).join(' ')
                }

            } else if (unitIndex === -1) {
                // There is no unit and No number in the 1st position
                objIng = {
                    count: 1,
                    unit: '',
                    ingredient 
                }
            }

            return objIng;
        });
        this.ingredients = newIngredients;
    }
}
```

`r.parseIngredients()` should display the ingredients units abbreviated. **ex: 4 tablespoons should be 4 tbsp.**

Comment: Please simplify the code by creating a Minimal, [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Doing so may allow you to figure out your problem.

Comment: If the error is the only thing that you see in the console then your `console.log()` statements did not run - and thus `window.r` assignment has not been executed, that is why you get an undefined variable.